# Laptop asks to dual-boot from external hard drive that is not even connected

Tags: dual-boot, windows, external-hdd

I have a single-boot Ubuntu running on my laptop. My previous laptop had a Windows/Ubuntu dual boot option. I extracted my previous laptop's hard drive, and plugged into my new laptop (with my new laptop already being booted) just to access some of the data from the external. When I was done using the external hard drive, I unmounted each of the separate drives on the external drive from the main filesystem and just pulled the external hard disk out. I did not know there is a "safely remove hard disk" option. I just unplugged the external after unmounting.

Now, when I boot my laptop, it asks me to go through the dual boot option, the option which I had on my previous laptop. My new laptop does not even have Windows, but it shows boot through Windows option, even though the external hard drive is not connected. How do I remove this option? I am worried if I boot using Windows, with there being no Windows OS on the laptop, I am going to crash my laptop and I don't want that. I am new at using Ubuntu and dual-boot, so I don't know what I did wrong and how I should rectify it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Linux version**

```
Linux 5.3.0-7625-generic x86_64
```

**OS Release**

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

PS - Sorry for any wrong terminology or format that I have used over here.

Comment: A possible simple fix: open a terminal and type `sudo update-grub`, supply your password when asked. It should detect the operating systems that are present. If it comes back with "found windows boot manager" then more work will be required but still do-able.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: @OrganicMarble: This is what it says:                                                               `Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-7625-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-7625-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-46-generic`